# I am unable to execute C++ program files on any of the text editors. What should I do now?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, error-handling, codeblocks, atom-editor

I have followed every tutorial on YouTube on setting up C++ in VS Code and Atom done everything they suggested, installed every required package. Error is coming for the input-output header file that is iostream.h in Atom, VS Code, Dev C++, CodeBlocks.

I think that the error is arising from the problem that my MingW's bin isn't containing g++.exe file but it is having g++.

After doing everything again and again  I am facing this same issue in every text editor-

```
include errors detected. please update your include path
```

and

```
cannot open source file"iostream"
```

[image: vs code snapshot]

[image: codeblocks snapshot]

[image: dev C++ code]

[image: devoutput]

[image: mingw bin folder]

Comment: use Visual Studio https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: I'd recommend using visual studio on windows if you're a c++ novice, its much easier to setup than mingw and the various editors you've been using

Comment: I don't think you have followed any tutorial properly as your vscode workspace has no `.vscode` folder, which in turn should have been containing `c_cpp_properties.json`. Moreover, it is not `iostream.h` but `iostream`. Also, include errors doesn't necessarily mean that there will be a compilation error. It simply shows that intellisense is not able to find that header. Try compiling the version you wrote on VS Code it should compile. To remove include errors follow the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). PS: which of these screenshots is of Atom?

Comment: why don't you try the same file in all the different editors

Comment: @rioV8 it doesn't matter if I try the same file in different text editors, the error keeps on coming in iostream

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have tried VS code but it isn't working.

Comment: visual studio and visual studio code are entirely separate products

Comment: @brc-dd I followed each and every step, mandatory and alternative. I have been working with C++ for the last two years on turbo C++ dos box so coming up with iostream.h is just a reflex. I also tried to execute the file with iostream but it didn't trigger any changes. I might have attached the snapshot of the code with iostream.h. Also, the error is the same in atom so I didn't attach its snapshot.

Comment: @AlanBirtles sorry I didn't read your answer properly but yes I've tried visual studio too. I am a first-year student and some senior recommended me Visual Studio Code over Visual Studio.

Comment: @SaniyaKhan In codeblocks you have created a `.c` file. It should be a C++ file. Also, can you show us the command you are using to compile? It should be `g++` not `gcc`. Moreover, compiler is not configured on Code::Blocks. You need to change its settings. You should have directly installed its with-MinGW version, or better install Visual Studio.

Comment: I formatted my C drive, now I am able to run C++ files without any errors. Thank you for reading my query and helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this:
#include <iostream>
// i. e. without extention ".h"
```

On the contrary to C, the C++ standard header file have no `.h` extension.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding explanation to your answer.